# PySpark: Merge two dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark

I‘m a beginner in python coding and more advanced in C+ and Js.
However maybe you can help me.

I have two dataframes, called df1 and df2. Both of them have different columns as well as lengths.

Df1:

| Id-name | Match | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21171 | 2500B | Title1 |
| 21171 | 2400B | Title2 |
| 21171 | 2400C | Title3 |
| 21171 | 3000A | Title4 |
| 22000 | 1000A | Title5 |

Df2:

| Prio | Document |
| --- | --- |
| 2500B | Doc1 |
| 2500B | Doc2 |
| 2500B | Doc3 |
| 1000A | Doc5 |
| 1000A | Doc6 |
| 1000A | Doc7 |
| 1000A | Doc8 |

Output:

| Id-name | Match | title | Prio | Document |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21171 | 2500B | Title1 | 2500B | Doc1 |
| 21171 | 2500B | Title1 | 2500B | Doc2 |
| 21171 | 2500B | Title1 | 2500B | Doc3 |
| 21171 | 2400B | Title2 | null | null |
| 21171 | 2400C | Title3 | null | null |
| 21171 | 3000A | Title4 | null | null |
| 22000 | 1000A | Title5 | 1000B | Doc5 |
| 22000 | 1000A | Title5 | 1000B | Doc6 |
| 22000 | 1000A | Title5 | 1000B | Doc7 |
| 22000 | 1000A | Title5 | 1000B | Doc8 |

I already tried with the union function to merge the dataframes but without any success.
Can somebody help me? Or tell me a proper way to do so.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying here is a join (left-join in fact, as there are NULL values in `Prio` column upon join).

you can do it as follows:

```
Df1.join(Df2, Df1['Match'] == Df2['Prio'], how='left')
```

Comment: The problem with join is that it only displays the last found prio number. It is not adding a new row when there is a match. Is there a way to add a row everytime when its a match

Comment: What do you mean adding new rows upon matches here?

Comment: Like the Output, everytime when df1['Match'] == df2['Prio'] a new row with the same df1 information will display. Only the df2 information will change.

Comment: Yes, do you want the whole information from both data -rames or only selective information? As, from your sample data, it seems you only need df1 combined with any information from df2.

Comment: In best case whole information from both dataframes, because the origin tables have more columns then the example ones

Comment: @Blaze, in that case, you can use a `full` join instead of `left` join. Change, `left` to `full` in `how` argument, it'd work.